# angular 2 promise to observable

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, observable

Following along the Angular 2 tutorial. I am trying to convert the following methods from `promises` to `observables`. My attempt is below.

1) Are the conversions corret?

2) How would I convert the `getGroup()` method

getGroups()

```
  // Promise
  getGroups(): Promise<Group[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.groupsUrl)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Group[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  // Observable
  getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.groupsUrl)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(response: Response) {
    let body = response.json();
    return body.data || { };
  }
```

getGroup()

```
  // Promise
  getGroup(id: number): Promise<Group> {
    return this.getGroups()
      .then(groups => groups.find(group => group.id === id));
  }
  // Observable
  // ================
  // HOW?
  // ================
```

createGroup()

```
  // Promise
  createGroup(name: string): Promise<Group> {
    return this.http
      .post(this.groupsUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  // Observable
  createGroup(name: string): Observable<Group> {
    return this.http
      .post(this.groupsUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
      .map(res => res.json().data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

updateGroup()

```
  // Promise
  updateGroup(group: Group): Promise<Group> {
    const url = `${this.groupsUrl}/${group.id}`;
    return this.http
      .put(url, JSON.stringify(group), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => group)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  // Observable
  updateGroup(group: Group): Observable<Group> {
    const url = `${this.groupsUrl}/${group.id}`;
    return this.http
      .put(url, JSON.stringify(group), {headers: this.headers})
      .map(() => group)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

deleteGroup()

```
  // Promise
  deleteGroup(id: number): Promise<void> {
    const url = `${this.groupsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http
      .delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => null)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  // Observable
  deleteGroup(id: number): Observable<void> {
    const url = `${this.groupsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http
      .delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
      .map(() => null)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Are the conversions correct?

Conversion isn't seems to be correct. By passing `function` references to the observable callbacks you are going to lose `this` context. You have to use `Arrow function` to keep touch in with `this` & call function explicitly.

```
// Observable
getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.groupsUrl)
      .map(this.extractData) //don't pass function reference
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

should be

```
// Observable
getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.groupsUrl)
    //.map(this.extractData.bind()) //this would work but its bad pattern
    .map(()=> this.extractData())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Follow the same thing for other functions if you did same thing over somewhere in your code.

> 2) How would I convert the getGroup() method

It will simply look like below

```
getGroup(id: number): Promise<Group> {
    return this.getGroups()
      .map(groups => groups.find(group => group.id === id));
}
```